# WHY Webservice Caching Token

Tags: mysql, linux, web-services, apache

I am using LAMP server, No matter what token service call has,
it's always showing me same number right now its 2147483647,
I guess it changes if I reboot server.

I have other values in the service call. I get all other correct except token.

Any help will be Appriciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps a web proxy or transparent cache between client and server?

Comment: all the other values are being passed properly, I thought it's naming issue and tried changing token to something else. still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is `(2 ** 32 / 2) - 1`. It is a classical symptom of OVERFLOW - for example, a 64 bit integer (or a unsigned 32 bit integer) assigned to a 32 bit signed integer.

I guess it is not caching the number - somewhere in the code (may be even inside some library) you are trying to store a larger number than a signed 32 bit integer can handle.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. I am not setting variable type for $token variable. if it's overflow how should I solve it ?

Comment: Sorry, the battery of my crystal ball just died, its impossible to tell without looking at your code. Join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6712/paulos and I will help you.